# How to remove comma from end of Google Sheets cell if it ends with a comma?

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, substitution

How to automatically trim a comma off? So I don't have to remove it manually?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can use regex for that like this:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1, ",$", )
```

[image: 0]

Comment: what does ,$ mean?

Comment: it means: "remove comma if a comma is at the far end"

Comment: not rly sure what you asking about... `REGEXREPLACE` is like a `SUBSTITUTE` formula, but more flexible. `SUBSTITUTE` can work with only what is present in cell while `REGEXREPLACE` can work with additional parameters like `$` in this case which can be translated as "from end" (`^` would be "from begining" so if you would had cell like `,a, b,` then you could do `=REGEXREPLACE(A1, "^,|,$", ))` where `|` means "and")

Answer (score 2):

```
=IF(RIGHT(B2,1)=",",LEFT(B2,LEN(B2)-1),B2)
```

Using `IF` and `LEN`.

If the last character of a cell value is a comma, then the answer should be the length of the cell minus the last character (the comma)

If the last character is not a comma, just pass the original value.

Answer (score -1):

Substitute works pretty well..it allows you to select which occurence

```
=SUBSTITUTE(L2,",","")
```

[image: Google Sheets Substitute function]